# Background/foreground color problem on Emacs on Windows

Tags: windows, emacs

I'm using Emacs on Windows.

In my .emacs file, I changed the background and foreground colors.

When I opened Emacs, the color changes occurred.

But when I opened a new frame using `C-x 5 2`, the color changes did not occur.

Why?

Comment: How exactly did you change the background and foreground colors?

Comment: You should check out color-theme: https://gna.org/projects/color-theme/ - it works nice on Windows and changes more than just background and foreground colors.

Comment: @Trey: I had two lines: `(set-background-color "black")` and 
`(set-foreground-color "white")`.

Comment: Yang Yah, you set the colors, but not the default ones.  Happens all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
(setq default-frame-alist
       `((background-color . "darkslateblue")
         (foreground-color . "lightcyan")))
```